# redraw MediaController controls

Tags: android, video, mediacontroller

Is their a way to redraw the MediaController controls when rotating the device? I am already overriding the onConfigurationChanged() method. I just don't know of the method to redraw the controls.

The reason for me wanting to do this is when I rotate, the controls dont resize to the screen width until they disappear and come back (tap the video again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would try (having no experience with MediaController, admittedly) is something like this:

```
MediaController mController = (MediaController)findViewById(R.id.mController);
mController.invalidate();
//next line may not be necessary
mController.show(some integer value here);
```

You might just be able to call `mController.show()` and it redraw it.

Comment: That sounds like it would work, but it doesn't. Before I posted this, I tried `mController.hide()` in the `onConfigurationChanged()` method which I assumed would just hide the controls on rotation thus when the video is clicked, the proportioned controls would pop up correctly. Oddly enough, no matter what I do when the screen rotates, the video controls ALWAYS pop up (wrong proportions though), regardless of what code I insert.

Comment: Alright so I think I found a viable solution. On rotation I set the VideoView's media controller to null and then reset it back to mController.

What that does is on rotation, the controls are removed and then reset thus when clicking on the video to make them visible, they are shown at the correct size.

http://pastie.org/1912047